# How do I invert the helper functions for dplyr::select?

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I invert the helper functions for `dplyr::select()`(like `matches()` or `contains()`) so that I can select variables that do NOT contains or match a particular string?

For example, say I wanted to select all the columns in the mtcars data frame that did not have the letter "m" in them. I could imagine doing something like:

```
mtcars %>%
    select( !matches("m") )
```

But that throws the error:

`Error: !matches("m") must resolve to integer column positions, not a logical vector`

How do I write the helper function to invert it?

Important note: one possibility is to use `matches()` and write a regular expression that doesn't match, but I'm more interested in finding a way to maintain the simplicity of the helper functions but invert the selection they return, rather than solving the actual "how do I select such-and-such" problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The helper functions for `select()` like `matches()`, `contains()`, `starts_with()` and so on, return a vector of index values. In the example above, if we didn't want the inverse, `matches("m")` would return `c(1,9)` because the first and ninth column names contain "m".

With that in mind, all we have to do is make the function negative:

```
mtcars %>%
    select( -matches("m") )
```

That makes `matches("m")` return a vector of `c(-1, -9)` which deselects those columns but leaves everything else.

Using `!`, the boolean `NOT`, as shown the in the original example, coerces the integer values to logical, so instead of `c(1,9)`, you end up with `c(FALSE, FALSE)` since both 1 and 9 coerce to `TRUE` but then are inverted by the `!`.

This explains the error R was throwing above--`select()` wants a list of integers, corresponding to column indexes, not a vector of logical values.